# Image rectangles and screen sizes

Tags: android, image, canvas

i am having a problem with canvas, rectangles and screen sizes:

[image: the issue]

I do not know whats wrong, because i am using the exact same code in both emulators, here is the code:

clouds is a plain object that contains the image and some methods to move them, this is how i create the clouds:

The clouds are all in one file, the coordinates are the rectangles where the single clouds are.

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        Cloud c;
        if (i == 1) c = new Cloud(5, 5, 245, 145);
        else if (i == 2) c = new Cloud(340, 30, 480, 130);
        else if (i == 3) c = new Cloud(565, 30, 725, 130);
        else c = new Cloud(830, 20, 980, 130);

        c.SetX(0);c.SetY(i * 150);


        //c.ReubicarNube();
        Clouds.Add(c);
    }
```

The constructor of Cloud class call this to handle the images (Plain is the super class of cloud):

```
public Plain(int ResourceImg, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){


    this.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Init.GetContext().getResources(), ResourceImg);
    this.Width = right - left;
    this.Height = bottom - top;
    this.frameImg = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    this.rect = new Rect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);

    Log.v("Plains", this.frameImg.toString() + " " + this.rect.toString());
}
```

and this is how I draw:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {     
    canvas.drawBitmap(img, frameImg, rect, Init.PaintFilter);
    //canvas.drawbi
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I've had issues like this in HTML5, where it turned out to be a markup issue with the dimensions. Which might be a clue to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!,

I fogot to put the image in the drawable-hdpi folder!, thats why i wasn't working!!

Thanks!